# Не выполняются миграции, ошибка при создании индекса

Tags: laravel, миграция

```
php artisan migrate
```

Результат:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   (SQL: alter table `articles` add constraint
>   articles_category_id_foreign foreign key (`category_id`) references
>   `categories` (`id`) on delete cascade)
>
> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign
>   key constraint

Миграция:

```
class CreateArticlesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->string('url')->unique();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->text('keywords')->nullable();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('category_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('categories')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['category_id']);
        });

        Schema::drop('articles');
    }
```

Engine: InnoDB (по умолчанию)

Актуальное решение проблемы найти не смог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно, но проблема решилась следующим образом.

```
Schema::table('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->foreign('category_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('categories')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Я поместил в миграцию категорий, так как из ошибки было понятно что он не может найти таблицу `categories` что бы на основе её `primary` связать `foreign`.

Однако, все делают так как изложено в вопросе, странно почему у меня это не сработало.